# Referencing 3rd party libraries and headers on a TFS build agent

Tags: tfsbuild

Until now our teams worked with VSS and we are in the middle of process to move to TFS2010 and VS2010.
Most of our code is C++ and we use a lot of 3rd party libraries such as Boost, OpenCV, OpenSSL and others.
Based on best practices I read, I am considering a few options to handle 3rd party headers and libraries in our multiple solutions and projects.

1. I create a standalone TFS Project for all 3rd party libraries and store sources/includes/outputs in it per library and per version. For example:

   ```
   Dependencies\
     -> Boost\
            ->boost_ver1\*
            ->boost_ver2\*
     -> OpenSSL\
            ->openssl-ver1\*
            ->openssl-ver2\**
   ```
2. My TFS source tree looks like:

   ```
   $\
       -> Dependencies\
       -> TeamProject1\
       -> TeamProject2\
       -> TeamProject3\
   ```
3. Our TeamProject(s) may contain multiple solutions on different levels in a folder tree.
4. I prepare a `dependencies.props` file per Team Project that all projects of given Team Project import into. That .props file adds relevant 3rd party packages to `$(IncludePath)` and `$(LibraryPath)`. In order to do this I assume that Dependencies project is mapped to a a folder defined by a global environment variable per machine per user.

I have a few questions regarding this approach:

1. I don't know how to make it work on a build agent because I can't specify environment variable in a Workspace mapping tab of a Build definition. I understand that BuildDirectory var and SourceDir var are changed per build.
2. How to make sure I get latest relevant third party dependencies before I start build any TeamProject solution.
3. Is this a "good" approach at all?

Comment: NuGet is supposedly getting native c++ support in the next few months if you can wait that long.  However I would like to point out that it's normally recommended to not split projects into their own Team Projects in TFS unless you have a good reason (http://blog.hinshelwood.com/one-team-project/)

Comment: Betty, I prefer to use multiple team projects because we have a very different scheduling release time and many builds to handle.

Answer (score 0):

1: If you want your build to determine something like which set of dependencies required from the build definition itself, you can pass in parameters to your process template using msbuild parameters or powershell parameters.  You can also have your logic pull the information from your props file as long as the generic dependencies and that file are included in your workspace.

2:  As long as the source control path containing the dependencies are mapped in the build definition it will sync the latest version from source control before building your solution and will have them before the solution builds.

3:  Not particularly for your case.  I recommend not using a generic dependencies area, because if you do something like gated builds, you will have all 3 builds popup in your gated check-in window.  Furthermore, changes to one solution can feasibly effect all three inadvertently.  Have you considered using nuget?  This is perhaps the best practice for keeping your 3 solutions separate and also have dependencies that can be used by some or all of them.  For example, most common dependencies for most coding efforts have downloadable nuget packages that will be downloaded during build without even having to check them in.